# Need to display mjpeg format live streaming video on Web page

Tags: .net, mjpeg, video-player

I need to display live streaming video in mjpeg format on My web page(in .Net Project), I tried with many different player but no proper solution found, any one help me on this? previously I used VLC player but now chrome remove support for it. any alternative?
I m using live Streaming of HTTP link.

Comment: maybe you should convert the live stream ? - it looks like there is no other idea at Stackoverflow ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best approach to real time http streaming to HTML5 video client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921790/best-approach-to-real-time-http-streaming-to-html5-video-client)

Answer (score 0):

If I were in that position, I would seriously consider converting the video to a format that the HTML5 `video` tag can use.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4