# html5 live streaming options

Tags: html, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

What options are available for HTML5 Live streaming?

I'd like to setup my own live streaming server somehow which grabs video sources from the database and dumps them into some sort of live video stream.

Before I actually start developing anything I'd like to first find out what protocols are available for me to use like RTSP and such. I have read about a several of the available choices like RTSP it self and DASH but I'm not too sure which of those are the current most supported protocols and have the best libraries available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best approach to real time http streaming to HTML5 video client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921790/best-approach-to-real-time-http-streaming-to-html5-video-client)

Answer (score 0):

Support for live video is still very fragmented. The options are basically as follows. RTMP/HLS/DASH in flash (may require custom development). HLS in safari. Media Source Extensions in Internet Explorer 11+, Chrome and Safari OS X, but not iOS. WebRTC in everything except safari and edge. You can also take a hybrid approach, like HLS with javascript conversion to fMP4 (Media Source Extensions).