# How to setup a live video stream from a Camera

Tags: video, camera, server, video-streaming

We are building a home security suite which includes a camera.
We want to give our users the ability to stream video live from anywhere.

However, I am not sure how I can access the camera since it will be behind the router. We dont want the user to set up port forwarding on the router.

Is there a way in which the camera can directly stream to our servers on demand?
Do we need a specific type of server to stream video's from the camera to the user?

I realize that this is very general sounding question, but I am not even sure what terms to use to describe the issue. I dont even know what to search for in Google. I am hoping stackoverflow will provide me a starting point.

Comment: Is something like this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921790/best-approach-to-real-time-http-streaming-to-html5-video-client

Comment: @Mark TY. But I am not looking to stream over HTML5.
I am looking for something along the lines of IP streaming or socket based