# How to stitch/concatenate/merge two mp4 blobs in the browser?

Tags: javascript

I have two mp4 blobs I need to combine on a browser client. Performance is important. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want performance _and_ be performed on user browser? All I can think of involves FFmpeg, but that's server-side

Comment: Actually there is an option to run ffmpeg client site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280149/863110

Comment: @MoshFeu isn't that library enormous to download on a client?

Comment: According to [bundlephobia](https://bundlephobia.com/result?p=ffmpeg.js@4.2.9003) it's 1.8MB gzipped. Not the end of the world.

Comment: I'm not expert with Blobs and I don't know if merging blobs are like concating strings like part1 + part2 = part1part2 but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876873/863110) might help

Comment: @MoshFeu Unfortunately mp4 blobs can't be simply concatenated. There is information in the header and footer, and key frame intervals (and other things) may vary between blobs.