# Live streaming of video in HTML web page using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to live stream live my CCTV camera video in web page using jQuery.

Camera URL is: `rtsp://admin:11111@103.75.35.102/streaming/channels/1`

Any help will be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best approach to real time http streaming to HTML5 video client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921790/best-approach-to-real-time-http-streaming-to-html5-video-client)